# 403 error response when submitting a post request to Instagram

Tags: c#, https

I'm trying to "programmatically" login to Instagram with a HTTP post request. Although, whenever I try to do it to this URL: https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ - it gives me a 404 error. However, if I remove the slash from the end, e.g. /accounts/login, then it will work, however, the response body just seems to be a simple GET request as they simply just output the same as if it was a GET request. I'm actually expecting an error message as response.

The code is written in C# and is nothing fancy; basically a http [web request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then I write the post data in the TCP stream. The website is using a CSRF token which needs to be included in the post request, so I first grab this key by using a simple GET request, and then continuing with the POST.

Is there any technical aspect that I'm missing? I've tried the code and done the same on several other websites and all attempts were successful.

The code looks much like this (same problem):

```
    WebResponse Response; 
HttpWebRequest Request;
Uri url = new Uri("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/");

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Request.Method = "GET";
Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

// Get the first response to obtain the cookie where you will find the "csrfmiddlewaretoken" value
Response = Request.GetResponse(); 

string Parametros = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value + "&username=USER&password=PASSWORD&next="; // This whill set the correct url to access

Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); // it is important to use the same url used for the first request
Request.Method = "POST";
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Request.UserAgent = "Other";
// Place the cookie container to obtain the new cookies for further access
Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
Request.Headers.Add("Cookie",Response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie")); // This is the most important step, you have to place the cookies at the header (without this line you will get the 403 Forbidden exception                                                   

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parametros);
Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

Response = Request.GetResponse(); // Fails here
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll probably receive better answers if you include your code in your question.

Comment: Yeh, the code has been included now.

Comment: `"&username=USER&password=PASSWORD&next="` contains the correct combination in your code? Also, do you have a "instagram capable" device at your hands, so that you can check the sent headers, for instance with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)?